# Isabelle/HOL: Is there a concise notation for an arbitrary value of a type?

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle/HOL, I can denote an arbitrary (but fixed) value of any type by `(SOME _. True)`. Is there a more concise notation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined`

(I wish I could just write the above, but answers must be longer than 9 characters.)